# Azure VM shutdown exception

Tags: shutdown, azure-vm-scale-set

I'm trying to create an automatic task for 2 DB machines in our Azure environment.
I'm using the built in Microsoft tool inside of the machine properties. ( Tasks under the Autmation window).

I need the machine to be up and running everyday **except friday and saturday**.

Can this task be done while using this window?
(Attached a screenshot of the window).

Thank you in advanced for your reply.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a solution...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devtest-labs/devtest-lab-auto-startup-vm

but for some reason i can't see the "**

- configurations and policies

**".

You can see this in the screen shot, it's marked in red!
I'll be posting a new post for this issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).